# Can I have a css div class mock a different css div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using bootstrap for my site.  I love the look and I want to make some changes to a ton of different blog post to include the bootstrap style.  I don't want go through hundreds of post to change the div's class element.  Can I do something like this:

```
<div class="important_note">
this is a old note that I want to use bootstrap styling on.
</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
.important_note{
  mimick(.alert)
}
</style>
```

alert is a bootstrap styling.

I apologize if this is a simple question, but web dev isn't much my thing.  I also couldn't find any similar questions.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, you can't do that. You'll have to upgrade your CSS.

Comment: You can use jQuery to add the `alert` class to all divs with `important_note`  class.

Comment: You could also use LESS. LESS allows for this. [here's the link to LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 1):

with css you can do the following:

```
.important_note, .alert{
//styling
}
```

this will apply the same styling to important_note and alert classes

Answer (score 0):

Without "upgrading" your CSS, if it's just about adding a class to each affected element, you can use a small script:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('important_note'), function(node) {
    node.classList.add('alert');
});
```

jQuery equivalent:

```
$('.important_note').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('alert');
}
```

Comment: This will work but OP please note that jQuery `.each()` is unbearably slow.

Comment: @Phillip That really depends on the context in which it's run; if you're talking about 1000+ elements, maybe.